understanding how sitemap and canonical meta tag combination work
If i have a website that has 2 locales for example www.example.com/en and www.example.com/es, are these considered duplicates therefore canonical meta tag should be used for one of them so that search engines can focus on crawling and indexing the most valuable one ? and when using sitemap should both urls be put like this, i'm new to SEO and im not sure how sitemap and canonical meta tags should be used

export default async function sitemap() {

  return [
    {
      url: `www.example.com/en`,
      ...
    },
    {
      url: `www.example.com/es`,
      ...
    },
  ];
}


